# fadeIn(); box-element with jQuery and CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with jQuery and showing a element that I would like to show as a box..
-webkit-box / -moz-box etc

BUT. If I use the fadeIn function in jQuery it fades into a block-element? 
I guess this is a common issue but I couldn't find anything that will help me.

Any tips?

CSS

```
.page-wrapper {
min-height: 100%;

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;

display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-align: center;
-moz-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;
}
#open-menu {
position: fixed;
color: #fff;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
font-size: 2em;
padding: 5px;
}
#page-wrapper-menu {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
display: none;
}
```

jQuery-code

```
$('#open-menu').click(function(){
    $('#page-wrapper-menu').fadeIn();
});
$('#page-wrapper-menu').click(function(){
    $('#page-wrapper-menu').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: fadeIn() sets css display to block by design.

Comment: Provide code you using, that might will help to understand your problem more clearly.

Comment: Flea777 yeah, I know, but how can I have the same effect but make it fade into a box-element.

Comment: You could create a single css rule (e.g. .box) with all the browser-dependant rules. Than, inside your animation, toggle only that css class with a fade effect. It should work because every browser will render its own rules.

Comment: Flea777 thats nice, but could that be animated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here you can achieve fade effect with change in display property of css. inline, or inline-block or block or any other..

```
$('').animate({display:"inline-block"},500);
```

Comment: Tryed this, but since it needs different codes for each browser I don't know how this would work :/

Comment: what code you wrote is right. you don't have to give box property for every browser. you give one normal rule and you will get same result in all browsers